# iPhone: force audio output to speaker with headphones plugged in

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, speaker, headphones

It seems that the accepted way of doing this is to set the AV category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, and then set the property kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker. I'm using the category AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, because it gives me the proper volume with the headphones not plugged in. When I set the category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, the audio playback through the speaker with the headphones not plugged in is very soft. I wasn't able to get the desired behavior of playback through the speaker with headphones plugged in with EITHER AV category.

Here's my code with the category set to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback:

```
    AVAudioSession* session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError* error  = nil;
    BOOL success = [session setActive: YES  error: &error];
    if (success)
        success     = [session setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback  error: &error];

    // To allow ipod music to play
    UInt32 doSetProperty = 1;
    AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof (doSetProperty), &doSetProperty);

    AudioSessionAddPropertyListener(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange,            hardwareRoutePropertyListener,  nil);

    UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
    AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,
                            sizeof (audioRouteOverride),
                            &audioRouteOverride
                            );
```